# PHP: Echo Failure via $_GET

Tags: php, strip-tags

I am currently displaying errors on my website using this code:

```
<?php
$failure = strip_tags($_GET['failure']);
if($failure!=""){
echo '<div class="error">';
echo $failure;
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

However, I am curious if this is safe. Is it?

Comment: What Pekka says is dandy, but a better solution would be to define all errors in an array or a function then access them by passing a $_SESSION variable that you set when the error occurred

Comment: Fair point @Lawrence, although it's a bit more complicated to implement if you have dynamic data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while this solution would change a little bit your approach, why not have an **errors.php** file with this structure?

```
$error[1] = 'some error message';
$error[2] = 'some other error message';
$error[3] = '...'; // you get the point
```

And the just send an ID as the error:

```
somepage.php?failure=2
```

Then, include this code where you usually display your errors:

```
if($_GET['failure'] && array_key_exists($_GET['failure'],$error) {
    echo $error[$_GET['failure']];
}
```

Just be sure to include **errors.php** in your **config.php** file (or whatever your main configuration's file name is).

**Why?**

1. Errors are often repeated, this way you can use them over and over again.
2. If you want to translate the site to another language, this system will be very helpful.
3. If you need to change a word on an error message, you will just have to change it once in the errors.php file.

IMHO it is much **much** safer to use ints than strings in this case.

Comment: +1 Better, but why not store the error integer in a session var then the is no room for manipulation

Comment: +1, totally agree. URLs should not be defining output, only specifying it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that would work too, but we don't know if the user will be requesting the page from an action in the same domain or not.

Comment: @Renesis +1 for your quote. That should be the main answer in this thread hehe.

Comment: This sounds the safest for me. I'll go with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can (and of course *always should*, hat tip @DaveRandom) do a `htmlspecialchars()` after `strip_tags` in order to prevent some clever construction from getting past the tag stripper. I have never seen a working exploit doing that successfully but it can't hurt taking additional precautions.

If you do all that, this looks safe.

Note that there is a limit on the maximum size of a GET request - 1kb is a safe maximum amount.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, you probably want to do that even if you're not `totally paranoid` - an error message could conceivably legitimately contain any of `<>&`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of PHP you have, `filter_input()` is a decent alternative.